# Same data read by PCF instances for spring batch application

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on a spring batch application,which read data from data base using JdbcCursorItemReader,this application is working as expected when I run a single instance.

I deployed this application in PCF and used auto scale feature, but multiple instances are retrieving the same record from the data base.

How can I prevent the duplicate data reads from other instances?

Comment: If you run the same query, you'll get the same data.  What, exactly, are you attempting to do?

Comment: I am reading data from the table by using status_nm column where value is new,can you please suggest me how can i lock these records so that other instance could not pick it.i tried select for update query but in this case when i am calling update or delete i am getting deadlock.i know if records are retrieved by select for update it should be updated or deleted using current of clause,can you please help me how to use current of sql using java.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is normally handled by applying the processed indicator pattern.  In this pattern, you have an additional field on each row that you mark with the status as each record is processed.  You then use your query to filter only the records that match the status you care about.  In this case, the status could be node specific so that the node only selects records that node tags.

Comment: if i use the processed indicator pattern means record is updated with some indicator say in_process, suppose i read 500 record from db and commit interval is say 100 then in_process indicator will get committed in data base after reaching commit interval.and it might be that second instance will read that data once again from DB as update is not committed that time.

Comment: The process indicator pattern has two parts.  The first is for the instance running to tag which items it's going to process via a listener.  Then, as they are processed, the indicator is changed to indicate that it's been successfully processed.

Comment: it will be great help if you can share some code example for this.as i am unable to get any example..